# How to extract 32x32 icon bitmap data from EXE and convert it into a PIL Image object?

Tags: python, icons, python-imaging-library, pywin32

I'm trying to extract a 32x32 icon from an EXE, and convert the bitmap data into an PIL `Image` object. My final goal is to compare the icon to another 32x32 PNG and get the difference with RMS.

I've tried doing `win32gui.ExtractIconEx()` then `win32gui.GetIconInfo()` and attemping to `Image.open()` on that, but PIL doesn't accept PyHANDLE objects, apparently. I've also attemped to open the exe directly with `Image.open()`, obviously that doesn't work.

I'm stumped right now, is there any way this is possible in Python or should I be writing this part of my code in a different language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a mailing list [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-April/009078.html), I found this code snippet:

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx("C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\mbam.exe",0)
win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, ico_x, ico_x )
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )
hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), large[0] )

hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, 'icon.bmp')
```

From there, you could load it into `PIL` in the normal `Image.open` fashion.

If you dig through the docs, you should be able to avoid the IO step and do it all in memory if you want. `PIL` has a from `frombuffer` method that you can use to convert the result of `GetBitmapBits` to an `Image` object.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding some code to convert it into an Image object, [this is what I ended up with](https://gist.github.com/ron975/7314682)

Comment: @ron975: broken link