# how to extract ico/png files from an exe in python

Tags: python, tkinter, ico, image-extraction

so im trying to make a little program launcher that takes the names of apps in a folder and make buttons with those names in a Tkinter window to that open the program that button specifies.  [image of python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjiPl.png).  so the program works, but i want to make the buttons have the icon of the app they start. so i was wondering if anyone knew how to extract either .ico/.png files from an exe with python.

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263599/how-to-extract-128x128-icon-bitmap-data-from-exe-in-python this may be helpful ?

Comment: im on windows 11