PySide6 Pyinstaller application icon not shown correctly
I'm trying to make a standalone (one file) Python app with custom icon displayed in Windows taskbar, QMainWindow left top edge and the executable file itself.
I was able to configure PyInstaller to assign .ico file to the executable itself and it is displayed properly
(guess assigning .png with transparent pixels also did work).
However I keep seeing default Python app icon in both taskbar and QMainWindow edge.
I have tried multiple .ico file locations and also did configure .spec file accordingly.
Also if I run application from IDE, the edge icon is displayed as expected.
Supposedly .spec file is missing some datas field value but didn't manage to find how to fix it.
Would welcome any suggestions.
test.py:
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World Application")
        label = QLabel("Hello, World!", self)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./app_icon.ico"))
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

PyInstaller:
PyInstaller --onefile --noconsole -i='./app_icon.ico' --name "TestApp" ".\test.py"
resulting test.spec:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['test.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('app_icon.ico', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='test',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['app_icon.ico'],
)

app_icon.png (converted to .ico with convertio.co/png-ico/)
Located in the root of the project:



Most certainly you're using the wrong path: you're copying the icon in . (the current directory of the package), but you're still trying to load it from the relative path. Try to change to app_icon_path = "./app_icon.ico"

Ah yes. As I was playing around with .ico file location, I put it into two directories.
However both approaches (original and proposed by you) give the same results.
I still can't see taskbar+edge icons in Pyinstalled application.
So speaking shortly - app_icon_path = "./app_icon.ico" gives the same result.

This still may be caused by a wrong path. Please take your time to [edit] your post and provide an accurate [mre] using correct paths. We cannot help you with code using unreliable paths that only work in a specific environment we know nothing about. Also, Windows uses an internal caching for icons, try renaming the exe file or copying it to another location and check again. Also, we must be aware about your pyinstaller usage: if you used the onefile option, then that's a different matter, and (again) we cannot really help you without knowing such important aspects.

Well, after a few tries I didn't succeed in what I initially tried.
Till now I tried to enpack image files into destination .exe file and expected to access them through relative path in my python code.
Apparently this does not work.
However there is way around it.
Luckily Pyinstaller has no issues in attaching icon to .exe file itself.
Thus I found a script that reads out icon image of the executable file.
Found the script in this post. Thanks to Audionautics:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760913/how-to-extract-32x32-icon-bitmap-data-from-exe-and-convert-it-into-a-pil-image-o

Saving the icon from the same executable in order to show it is an inappropriate workaround, and it's not the solution to your problem (on the contrary, it can result in other problems). As already said, the problem may be with the wrong path or the usage of onefile (which we still don't know if you use), so please [edit] your post with what asked above.

Sure. I have updated the post. Answering you questions - Yes, I try to build single file executable (--onefile PyInstaller option). Also I don't think the issue is related to wrong path of icon. E.g. providing an absolute path worked but then result is dependent on icon file being present in the system. Playing around with file name and location also didn't help. Maybe if you could describe how it works on your side, guess I would be able to replicate your approach. Let me know if there is anything else I could provide.

Well, seems I found what I was missing.
Added a resource_path function that adjusts requested resource path dependent on if the program is being ran as a script or build executable.
Will add this solution proposal as a secondary comment.

Yes, it is a path issue, and the very fact that it works using an absolute path is the demonstration. The problem is that when using the onefile mode, the resources included in the package are not in the same path as the executable. You need to load them based on the fact that the program is in "frozen" (compiled) mode or not, and in the first case, construct the actual path in which those files are temporary stored. While the method you suggested below "works", is completely inappropriate, at least for this purposes: in-app resources must be loaded in the correct way.

For future reference, always ensure that you provide all relevant information. If you explained in detail how you were creating the installer in the original post, we would have been able to solve this in a few minutes, instead of the day after.

So after a few tries I found what was the issue.
Added function resource_path that switches route to desired resource based on whether app is being ran as a script or standalone executable:
Script:
import os
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """Get the absolute path to a resource (icon, etc.) bundled with the app."""
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder for bundled app resources
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            # Running in a bundled app
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        else:
            # Running in a normal script
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing resource: {e}")
        return None


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World Application")
        label = QLabel("Hello, World!", self)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(resource_path("app_icon.ico")))
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

CMD:
PyInstaller --onefile --noconsole -i='./app_icon.ico' --name "TestApp" ".\test.py"
